# Cайт через WebView и получение уведомлений

Tags: android, webview, уведомления, android-notification, android-webview

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать.
Есть сайт с регистрацией, авторизацией и большим функционалом. Сделал для него Android приложение которое просто открывает сайт через WebView.

Я хочу чтобы приложение показывало push-уведомления пользователю, когда на сайте ему приходят личные сообщение. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Если сайт большой, скорее всего на нем есть API. Реализуйте сервис, в котором будете получать информацию о сообщениях, и есть есть сообщение, создавать notification.

Comment: API нету. Я хочу чтобы пользователь просто пользовался сайтом через webview. Может при логине на сайте передавать какой-то идентификатор, привязывать его к профилю пользователя и посылать уведомления с его помощью. В общем нужно как-то связать пользователя на сайте и приложение используя при этом только возможности webview.

Comment: Значит надо парсить страничку на наличие новых сообщений. "Из воздуха" не получится получить)

Answer (score 0):

Копайте в сторону Firebase Cloud Messages. Есть API и хорошие примеры, которые можно адаптировать для своих нужд.